# Sql errror when running LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE on AWS with RDS

Tags: mysql, bash

I have an Ubuntu webserver on AWS communicating to a Mysql server on AWS RDS.
I keep getting an error with this SQL when running it from the Ubuntu Server. Any ideas why I could be having the problem. Any ideas why the sql is failing?

Basically I'm trying to load a file onto the mysql server. I need to be able to achieve this with BASH programatically.

```
$(mysql -h "$host" --user="$user" --password="$pw" --local-infile=1 -D"$DbName" --skip-column-names -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/html/results/F9_result.jtl' INTO TABLE `result.jtl` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY ' ' IGNORE 1 LINES;")
```

Error Message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to      your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY ' ', IGNORE 1 LINES' at line 1

Comment: You forgot to escape the backtics around `result.jtl`.

Comment: That was correct. -Thanks.  I now get an error:  Access denied for user 'userName'@'%' (using password: YES)- Any ideas?

Comment: The combination of `-h "$host" --user="$user" --password="$pw" -D"$DbName"` isn't right; perhaps there's some AWS controlpanel where you can verify the credentials?

Comment: I backslashed the back ticks around results.jtl which resolved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Escaping the back ticks as suggested resolved the problem  with the SQL

```
$(mysql -h "$host" --user="$user" --password="$pw" --local-infile=1 -D"$DbName" --skip-column-names -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/html/results/F9_result.jtl' INTO TABLE `result.jtl` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY ' ' IGNORE 1 LINES;")
```